# How to set value string datetime (from database) to <input type="date" ng-model="endtime" name="endtime" />

Tags: angularjs, string, datetime, datepicker

As my question, this is my first time using angularjs. I try to search the solution but nothing give extactly i want.
i have list data, when update row, row value will be added to table, with datetime column, when i edit, the value can not be set to date picker (angular).
My code.
html input tag:

```
<input id="endtime" type="date" ng-model="endtime" />
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.editJob = function (job) {
    debugger;
    var getData = EmployeeService.getJobByID(job.JobID);
    getData.then(function (emp) {
        $scope.job = emp.data;           
        $scope.endtime = job.EndTime;          
       ;
    },
    function () {
        alert('Error in getting records');
    });
}
```

Service.js

```
 // Update Job
this.updateJob = function (job) {
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "Employee/UpdateJob",
        data: JSON.stringify(job),
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return response;
}
```

Index page
[index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnovZ.jpg)

My string datetime value like : "3/1/2016"

p/s: sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u are using Html input type date. Then assign that variable with new Date("03/25/2015");

```
go through this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/HcXL2TptB90skqdQznvz?p=preview
```

Comment: seem like this is what i need, but how i can apply this to my code on Controller.js. Can u apply some in my controller. Sorry for ask this cause im new with this angularjs

Comment: In editJob function use this  $scope.endtime = new Date(job.EndTime)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.editJob = function (job) {
    debugger;
    var getData = EmployeeService.getJobByID(job.JobID);
    getData.then(function (emp) {
        $scope.job = emp.data;           
        $scope.endtime = $scope.job.EndTime;          
       ;
    },
    function () {
        alert('Error in getting records');
    });
}
```

Comment: var data = emp.data;           
  $scope.endtime = data.EndTime;    Try if this work

Comment: What is the type of value you are returning from service. That is String or Date. If it is String then you have to convert that to Date.

Comment: as i ask, my return value is string and i try to find out how to convert.